# Angular + PWA = No SSR?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, server-side-rendering, angular-pwa

I have configured an angular application with SSR, which works very well.

Now that I made my app a PWA using `ng add @angular/pwa`, the app is no longer pre-rendered.

I have to reload the page with Ctrl+Shift+R, then it is pre-rendered again.

I don't get an error message both in the Angular App and from my node server.

What can be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In ssr,

Do you have same error in SSR case please check " I have to reload the page with Ctrl+Shift+R, then it is pre-rendered again."  Is you meta tags are same on reload